# how to manage what send when close matdialog in angular material dialog

Tags: angular-material, mat-dialog

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gd5gcg?file=app/dialog-overview-example-dialog.html

In this example of the official documentation, I see that the value returned when you close the matdialog is this

```
 <button mat-button [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal" cdkFocusInitial>Ok</button>
```

But what happens if you want to send a value calculated in a function previously for example like this

```
getData(){
this.datos=[1,2,3,4];
```

}

How can you make that function be called before returning the value to the component that opened the matdialog?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quiet simple

```
 <button mat-button (click)="getData()" [mat-dialog-close]="data.animal"
```

Thanks